# VueJS Private IP APIs Call

Tags: laravel, vue.js, apache, devops

I have a Larave/VueJS app deployed on two separate virtual machines, One for backend with a private IP address,And the other One for Fronend with a private ip address also. And i have one public IP address that allowed to point to the Front-end machine IP only, Frontend machine can communicate with the backend machine, When i deploy the app on the Production server. Ally my APIs got "NETWORK FAILED" error, As the request is being initiated at client side, not the FE machine, What arch/solution i can follow to solve this issue, My web server is apache and os is ubuntu. Thank you.

I tried to to use normal API calling from VUE using axios lib.

Comment: Share the error please, and the code, you are saying "As the request is being initiated at client side, not the FE machine", that is exactly the same...

Comment: Actually there is no specific code, it is an entire app. the error is APIs network failed error as the API is trying to call www.mybackendAPI.com and this is a private IP VM, only accessible from the other Private IP ( FE VM ). so communication between VMs is working fine.

Comment: how are you passing a URL or IP to that JS app? Why is it not using the other IP?

Comment: I am passing it as a normal env variable. what is meant by other IP? i am passing Backend machine IP/

Comment: You are not passing the right value to whatever you use to the frontend, that is why we need code, else this is a "you vs me"

Comment: Some code examples would be pretty welcome here. Also, I'm not sure why even your front-end is hidden on a private IP tbh. What's the point of such configuration?

Comment: @kissu. it was required. anyways. the FE. is exposed on a public IP. that is allowed to communicate with the backend, Which is hidden on a private IP. As for the code sample. it is as simple as any Axios request.